# Unable to connect to adb daeomon on port:5037

Tags: android, android-emulator

[image]I have just installed the android studio, But my "Hello world " App is not running in emulator, It's showing the Emulator error - Unable to connect to adb daemon on port 5037[image]

Answer (score 15):

**1.) You can restart adb manually from command prompt**

```
  run->cmd->your_android_sdk_path->platform-tools>
```

Then write the below commands.

**adb kill-server** - To kill the server forcefully

**adb start-server** - To start the server

```
F:\android-sdk-windows latest\platform-tools>adb kill-server
F:\android-sdk-windows latest\platform-tools>adb start-server
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
* daemon started successfully *
```

Comment: but got this one error -  The program can't start because api-ms-win-crt-heap-|1-1-0.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstallling the program to fix this problem.

Comment: I have added new image of erroe, for fixing this I have added these files in system 32 and sysWOW64, but still am getting same error

Comment: https://www.thewindowsclub.com/api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0-dll-is-missing

Follow instruction on this link may solve your issue

Answer (score 4):

Go to platform-tools folder in `appdata` where `adb.exe` file resides.

Execute the following command:

```
adb reconnect offline
```

it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Sir , reinstall everything especially for Android Studio , reverse to older version if that's available , update to newest version if that's unavoidable

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was wiping the data of the emulator.

```
emulator -avd Your_Device_Name -wipe-data
```

Answer (score 0):

just do 2 things into your terminal below:

adb kill-server

adb start-server

write above 2 lines into your terminal problem will resolve.  thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had two Android Studios running (Stable and alpha). Closed both of them and then re-opened one, and was good again.